# how find index of max in each row of Opencv Mat object

Tags: opencv, neural-network, response

I have an OpenCv Mat.The Mat is response of MLP Neural Network. how can i find the index of maximum value in each row?

Comment: Run [`cv::minMaxLoc`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#minmaxidx) on each row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `minMaxLoc` to do this.

```
Mat img = imread("image.jpg"), row;

double min=0, max=0;
Point minLoc, maxLoc;

for (int i = 0; i < img.rows; i++)
{
    row = img.row(i);

    //maxLoc contains coordinate of maximum value
    minMaxLoc(row, &min, &max, &minLoc, &maxLoc);
}
```

Comment: the row is a 1 * N  Mat.  i want find the maximum value index(column)  not in cv :: Point  type  . number of column of maximum value

Comment: @sina The `maxLoc.x` is the column number of the maximum value in the row.

Answer (score 0):

Using minMaxIdx for each row (as mentioned before) might be more straightforward:
[cv::minMaxIdx](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=minmaxloc#minmaxidx)

Answer (score 0):

```
void GetMaxValueIndex(const cv::Mat src_mat) {
  double min_value;
  int minidx;
  std::vector<double> min_value_vec;
  std::vector<int> min_idx_vec;
  for (int i = 0; i < src_mat.rows; i++) {
    cv::minMaxIdx(cls_confs.row(i), &minvalue, NULL, &minidx, NULL);
    min_value_vec.push_back(min_value);
    min_idx_vec.push_back(min_idx);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).